# elasticsearch and scroll api (get more than 10000 records)

Tags: javascript, post, elasticsearch, get

I tried to use post search request with next body:

`{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"dateOfWork":{"gte":"01.01.2016","lte":"22.5.2017"}}}]}}}`

i have more than 20000 result records, but i cant get all of them because elastic search have 10000 records limit. (Dnt offer to increase max_result_window plz)

how can i use scroll api to get all results in 1 query?
I will be very grateful for a simple example (post/get requests or js code)?

Comment: You can´t get all in 1 query, need to do multiple queries.I would guess that as most apis, you have to specify an offset. In this case, I would guess the right parameter is from. So from 10000 would give you the other 10000

Comment: when i tried to use query `"from":10000,"size":10000` I get answer `Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [20000]`

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html